# Splitting data with inconsistent delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split, delimiter

I have these data files comming in on a server that i need to split into [date time] and [value]. Most of them are delimited a single time between time and value and between date and time is a `space`. I already have a program processing the data with a simple split(char[]) but now found data where the delimiter is a `space` and i am wondering how to tackle this best.

So most files i encountered look like this:

```
18-06-2014 12:00:00|220.6
```

The delimiters vary, but i tackled that with a char[]. But today i ran into a problem on this format:

```
18-06-2014 12:00:00 220.6
```

This complicates things a little. The easy solution would be to just add a `space` to my split characters and when i find 3 splits combine the first two before processing?

I'm looking for a 2nd opining on this matter. Also the time format can change to something like `d/m/yy` and the amount of lines can run into the millions so i would like to keep it as efficient as possible.

Comment: sounds like regular expressions would do a better job in this case

Comment: Is your date time format consistent (i.e. always going to be this length in characters)?

Comment: Do you mean single line not single time?

Comment: I would like a solution for different time formats like my previous solution until I encountered that that sob format :). Need to edit that in when back at pc.

Comment: For efficiency it's also important to know if the delimiters only vary per file or also per line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe the most efficient solution is to add space as a delimiter and then just combine the first two if you get three.  That is going to be be more efficient than regex.

Comment: And tackles multiple date/time formats. If true I'm happy with an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a string `18-06-2014 12:00:00 220.6` where first 19 characters is a date, one character is a separation symbol and other characters is a value. So:

```
var test = "18-06-2014 12:00:00|220.6";
var dateString = test.Remove(19);
var val = test.Substring(20);
```

Added normalization:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var test = "18-06-2014 12:00:00|220.6";
    var test2 = "18-6-14 12:00:00|220.6";
    var test3 = "8-06-14 12:00:00|220.6";
    Console.WriteLine(test);
    Console.WriteLine(TryNormalizeImportValue(test));
    Console.WriteLine(test2);
    Console.WriteLine(TryNormalizeImportValue(test2));
    Console.WriteLine(test3);
    Console.WriteLine(TryNormalizeImportValue(test3));
}
private static string TryNormalizeImportValue(string value) {
    var valueSplittedByDateSeparator = value.Split('-');
    if (valueSplittedByDateSeparator.Length < 3) throw new InvalidDataException();
    var normalizedDay = NormalizeImportDayValue(valueSplittedByDateSeparator[0]);
    var normalizedMonth = NormalizeImportMonthValue(valueSplittedByDateSeparator[1]);
    var valueYearPartSplittedByDateTimeSeparator = valueSplittedByDateSeparator[2].Split(' ');
    if (valueYearPartSplittedByDateTimeSeparator.Length < 2) throw new InvalidDataException();
    var normalizedYear = NormalizeImportYearValue(valueYearPartSplittedByDateTimeSeparator[0]);
    var valueTimeAndValuePart = valueYearPartSplittedByDateTimeSeparator[1];
    return string.Concat(normalizedDay, '-', normalizedMonth, '-', normalizedYear, ' ', valueTimeAndValuePart);
}       
private static string NormalizeImportDayValue(string value) {
    return value.Length == 2 ? value : "0" + value;
}
private static string NormalizeImportMonthValue(string value) {
    return value.Length == 2 ? value : "0" + value;
}
private static string NormalizeImportYearValue(string value) {
    return value.Length == 4 ? value : DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Remove(2) + value;
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but i run into problems again when the date format changes to something like 18-6-14.

Comment: If you can't ask a source of the data to normalize it, you can normalize it by yourself. I edited my answer to show how you can normalize date value, so datetime part always will be 19 characters. If you expect an invalid time format, you can also normalize it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this one to get the date and the value.

```
(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(19|20)\d\d)\s((\d{2}:?){3})|(\d+\.?\d+))
```

This will give you 2 matches

1º 18-06-2014 12:00:00 
2º 220.6

Example:
 http://regexr.com/391d3

Comment: I have to get into regular expressions some more to work this out myself. This will not work on "18/6/14", but there has to be a way with regex.

Comment: This does not work with / because you specified that the date format was 18-06-2014 12:00:00 when i saw it, if you want to match it, you just need to change - with (-|/) , - or /, and ur ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches both kinds of strings, capturing the two tokens to Groups 1 and 2.

- Note that **we are not using `\d`** because in .NET it can match any Unicode digits such as Thai...
- **The key** is in the `[ |]` character class, which specifies your two allowable delimiters

Here is the regex:

```
^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} (?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})[ |]([0-9]{3}\.[0-9])$
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/rE4lI2), please pay attention to the capture Groups in the right pane.

Here is how to retrieve the values:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} (?:[0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})[ |]([0-9]{3}\.[0-9])$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string mydate = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(mydate);
string myvalue = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(myvalue);
```

Please let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

Given the provided format I'd use something like

```
    char delimiter = ' '; //or whatever the delimiter for the specific file is, this can be set in a previous step
    int index = line.LastIndexOf(delimiter);
    var date = line.Remove(index);
    var value = line.Substring(++index);
```

If there are that many lines and efficiency matters, you could obtain the delimiter once on the first line, by looping back from the end and find the first index that is not a digit or dot (or comma if the value can contain those) to determine the delimiter, and then use something such as the above.

If each line can contain a different delimiter, you could always track back to the first not value char as described above and still maintain adequate performance.

Edit: for completeness sake, to find the delimiter, you could perform the following *once* per file (provided that the delimiter stays consistent within the file)

```
    char delimiter = '\0';
    for (int i = line.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var c= line[i];
        if (!char.IsDigit(c) && c != '.')
        {
            delimiter = c;
            break;
        }
    }
```